# Should i put the source code in the same folder as the source?

Tags: java

The default, well-know structure for a java application is:

```
/src/test/java/com/mypackage/mymodule
/src/main/java/com/mypackage/mymodule
```

I want to give a basic example. Lets say there is a module called 'image' which is responsible to create the database scheme, has a repository to save the images and provides a service to use this module.

I want to use this module in different projects, so I just created a git submodule and added it to both project. To make this complete i want to move the tests in this module as well so that every time i build one of the projects the tests gets executed. I don't want to manage the tests in one of the projects.

Is there any recommended way to handle this kind of problem ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Usually tests for module are stored in that module but in tests folder. So that if you change some internals of your module you need to run tests only for that module.

Let's say you have module A and projects P1 and P2 that use that module A as a dependency. Then unit tests for module A should be in repository for module A. In this case once build for module A finishes successfully you know that this module works OK.

If you have unit tests for code of module A in project P1 then you cannot test your build of module A without running build of project P1. And you may also need to run duplicated tests for code from module A in your another project P2 because if somebody removes module A from project P1 (and all unit tests for that code would be removed as well) then that module A will not have tests at all.

Comment: "Then unit tests for module A should be in repository for module A." Okay, but where should i store them ? Is there a recommended way to store them inside the repo ?

Comment: `src/main/java` is for production code, `src/test/java` is for unit (and other types) tests

Comment: okay but if add the submodule in Project1 the package structure would be /src/main/com/package/src/test/java/mymodule, or do i understand something wrong ?

Comment: In this case you need to build module separately and in main project add Maven (or Gradle) dependency

Comment: what is the benefit ? why not just put the tests in the same directory as the source expect that i pollute the output war/jar file ? I dont see any drawback

Comment: Config files might be different. For example we use Oracle database in Prod but inmemory hsqldb for unit tests. If you put tests together with prod code then all its dependencies will become transitive dependencies for a project which will use such module. Also all test configs will also be included into prod jar/war which may cause some hard to find bugs